# How can I scan through a directory in python?

Tags: python

I have a python script that is trying to compare two files to each other and output the difference. However I am not sure what exactly is going on as when I run the script it gives me an error as

```
NotADirectoryError: [WinError 267] The directory name is invalid: 'C:\\api\\API_TEST\\Apis.os\\*.*'
```

I dont know why it is appending * . * at the end of the file extention.

This is currently my function:

```
def CheckFilesLatest(self, previous_path, latest_path):

    for filename in os.listdir(latest_path):

        previous_filename = os.path.join(previous_path, filename)
        latest_filename = os.path.join(latest_path, filename)

        if self.IsValidOspace(latest_filename):

            for os_filename in os.listdir(latest_filename):
                name, ext = os.path.splitext(os_filename)

                if ext == ".os":
                    previous_os_filename = os.path.join(previous_filename, os_filename)
                    latest_os_filename = os.path.join(latest_filename, os_filename)

                    if os.path.isfile(latest_os_filename) == True:

                        # If the file exists in both directories, check if the files are different; otherwise mark the contents of the latest file as added.
                        if os.path.isfile(previous_os_filename) == True:
                            self.GetFeaturesModified(previous_os_filename, latest_os_filename)
                        else:
                            self.GetFeaturesAdded(latest_os_filename)

        else:
            if os.path.isdir(latest_filename):
                self.CheckFilesLatest(previous_filename, latest_filename)
```

Any thoughts on why it cant scan the directory and look for an os file for example?

It is failing on line:

```
for os_filename in os.listdir(latest_filename):
```

The code first gets called from

```
def main():
    for i in range(6, arg_length, 2):
        component = sys.argv[i]
        package = sys.argv[i+1]

        previous_source_dir = os.path.join(previous_path, component, package)
        latest_source_dir = os.path.join(latest_path, component, package)

        x.CheckFilesLatest(previous_source_dir, latest_source_dir)
        x.CheckFilesPrevious(previous_source_dir, latest_source_dir)
```

Thank you

Comment: It would help if you told us on what line the exception is raised.

Comment: Sorry, its failing on the line that states: for os_filename in os.listdir(latest_filename):

Comment: Can you check what are the argumetns to this function. Add a print statement at function entry point

Comment: What is the code that first calls CheckFilesLatest?

Comment: The code first gets called from def main(): x.CheckFilesLatest(previous_source_dir, latest_source_dir)

Comment: Have you checked the standard library's ``difflib``?  Depending on your needs, might do almost all the work for you...

Comment: I have never tried it but I will definitely take a look. I am trying to debug this code line by line and it seems that in the forloop on the line that states "ext = os.path.splitext(os_filename)" the variable ext is empty. Why is this? My variable of "os_filename" does indeed have a value but its actually the folder name and inside this folder are all the .os files

Comment: When you state that ext is empty do you mean that it is ('', '') or () or ''  What does it show when you say print os.path.splitext(os_filename) as well as print os_filename

Answer (score 1, accepted):

os.listdir() requires that the latest_path argument be a directory as you have stated. However, latest_path is being passed in as an argument. Thus, you need to look at the code that actually creates latest_path in order to determine why the '*.*' is being put in. Since you are calling it recursively, first check the original call (the first time). It would appear that your base code that calls CheckFilesLatest() is trying to set up the search command to find all files within the directory 'C:\api\API_TEST\Apis.os' You would need to split out the file indicator first and then do the check.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to browse a directory recursively, using `os.walk` would be better and simpler than your complex handling with recursive function calls. Take a look at the docs: http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.walk